# Qt Video works in simulator but not on Nokia devices

Tags: qt, qt4

Following is my code to play videos in Qt. In the simulator it works fine but not on Nokia devices. How can I fix this?

```
QVideoWidget* widget = new QVideoWidget(0);
QMediaPlayer *player; 
player = new QMediaPlayer; 

player->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/360x640/Mechanique2go.mp4"));  // Local file Path
player->setVideoOutput(widget);
player->setVolume(100); // line 23
player->play();
widget->raise();
widget->showFullScreen();
```

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you mean by "doesn't work".

Comment: Provide details on the Nokia device that you tested

Comment: Are you sure, that you deployed all required libraries and plugins? Also why do you call raise?

Comment: Lack of codec/bad video encoding? I found my N900 was having issues playing h264 made with mencoder with the built in player (same as Qt would end up using as backend), however mplayer on the same device could play the file.

Comment: I am testing it on Nokia 5800 Music Express and Nokia N8. NO any effects of raise() function. I have added video in .qrc file and then use it.

Comment: Is there any Other option than .qrc file to give path of video.

Comment: I didn't mean that raise does any effect, it does exactly nothing in this case, especialy when widget is still hidden

Comment: Ok I have Solve this Problem using Deployment in .pro file. But In Device I am not getting White Background. Only Video Part is seen. Remaining part seen Black. I use following code for that.  widget->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)");